# why there is no such thing [create landscape variation] but a [ landscape qualifier ] in Android Studio?

Tags: android, android-layout

I new in Android , and follow[ https://developer.android.com/codelabs/android-training-layout-editor-part-b#6 ] official study .
But I can find  [create landscape variation] in orientation button , only can find a  [ create landscape qualifier ] in somewhere else .
why this happen ? A version change ?

not found pic:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YLO83.png)

found qualifier pic :
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DdOoA.png)

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: so, it's matter project ? if use anther project code , I will find that button? there is no code , just follow [ https://developer.android.com/codelabs/android-training-layout-editor-part-b#6 ] website practical codelab . thank you